# Solving a partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

What are the steps to solve $$\frac{\partial ^{2}f}{\partial x\partial y}=0$$

Is this just $$\int fdx(\int fdy) = F(x) (F(y)$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it?

Comment: If $f(x,y)=xy$, then the second order mixed partial is $1$ not $0$.  So, you can't just separate it like that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Let $g=\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$.  Solve the equation $\frac{\partial g}{\partial x}=0$ first.  Say the solution to that is $G(y)$ (notice that the solution can only be a function of $y$).  Now solve $\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=G(y)$.  Without some condition, your answer will be general.